# Set Button on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

How I can set button on tableView. When I set any view or button on table view this occupy complete width of tableview and I can't change its width. How I can achieve it(Right Bottom Button). My UI is here:

[image]

Comment: consider a cell frame in cellForRowAtIndexpath and add a button of same frame .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button.center = self.view.center

Try

let cellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
button.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2.0, y: cellHeight / 2.0)
This assumes that your tableView is full width and your cellHeight is 44.0. You can't get the actual height from the cell itself just yet. If you want the actual height you'd have to get it from the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method or do something else.

Also instead of using self.myTable you should use the tableView variable in the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a button to table view, you should consider adding it to the superview of tableview.

What I mean is create a table view inside a view and add the button to same view.